# Searching for tweets with tweepy in Python

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, tweets

everything works fine with my code except this part:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r07Fd.png)

somebody help me correct this error.

Am using tweepy python module and the rest of the code is woking fine. Here is part of the code with problems:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxuep.png)

Thanks is advance.

Comment: please paste the code here, not only a screenshot of the code.

Comment: Also.. what are you actually trying to do? Fixing a bug requires us to know what the intended functionality is.

Answer (score 0):

try this in line number 26 `statuses=i['statuses']` or you can try this
 `statuses+=[i['statuses']]`